# excel | find row in different worksheet

Tags: excel, function

I have a worksheet with a table and some information (e.g. name, adress, phone, category).
The category contains a bundle of categories i can define and from that list I am looking for example all the rows that contain "police".

I've worked with the VLOOKUP("*police*";A2:D50;2;false).
2 issues right here:
1st this returns the first and not all the matches
2nd this returns only the value of one cell instead of the whole row

what i am trying to achieve here is:
looking through the table and find all the matches in the category.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to return the nth occurrence of "Police". [Read up on it here](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/11/10/vlookup-second-value/). However, if you don't know how many to expect this becomes problematic.

As for returning the entire row, worksheet functions can only display a value in the cell in which they reside, meaning you can't have a formula in one cell and a result in many. Array formulas might do that sort of thing. Google for "array formula" and read what C.Pearson or Contextures have to say.

Personally, I find array formulas too difficult. I find it easier to do the sort of thing you want using VBA.

Comment: I am totally with you. I would rather sort the table than use an array formula. 
but this task is for a friend of mine who doesn't want to take a look at the table, just use a searching "frame" and get results

Answer (score 0):

if you want a list of all the hits on "Police" I would do this in to steps.

1. In a cell type what your looking for, Ex `police` in `A1`
2. Then type `=IFERROR(SMALL(IF($B:$B=$A$1,ROW($A:$A)),ROW()),"")` press `CTRL+Shift+Enter` (assuming "police" is found in column "B")
   Drag Down as fare as needed. This way you get all the rows of that instance.
3. Now you can use `INDEX`to get what you need from those rows.

Comment: As fare as I could read in your question that was it. Might specify it some more.